# Setting query results encoding in cx_Oracle / UnicodeDecodeError with Chinese characters

Tags: python, encoding, cx-oracle

I'm working with a **database containing a lot of Chinese characters**. My code goes something like this:

```py
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("%s/%s@%s:%s/%s" % (username, password, host, port, service_name))
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT HOTEL_ID,CREATE_TIME,SOURCE,CONTENT,TITLE,RATE,UPDATE_TIME FROM T_FX_COMMENTS')

for row in cursor:
    # Stuff goes here
    pass
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    for row in cursor:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 26: illegal multibyte sequence
```

It seems `GBK` is not enough. **I want to make `cx-oracle` give me `GB18030` encoded results**, instead of `GBK`. How do I do this?

[`cx_Oracle.Connection.encoding`](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/connection.html#Connection.encoding) is read-only... I haven't found anything in the `cx-oracle` documentation that suggests I can do this.

I'm on Python 3.3.2 and `cx-oracle` 5.1.2.
There must be something I'm missing here. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Same scenario for me... did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue and I solved by setting the environment variable `NLS_LANG` to `.AL32UTF8` (it seems a sort of "wildcard" that says "use utf-8 for any language")

Comment: 3.5 years later, this also still works.  Python 3.6.3 + cx_Oracle 7.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the NLS_LANG environment variable at the beginning of your program:

```
import os
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".GB18030"
```

Comment: It's giving me this error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified`. I'm on Python 3.3.2 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import os
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".zhs16gbk"
```

os.environ["NLS_LANG"] is for Oracle.So use the format of Oracle.
I solved with this with my python 2.6.8 and Oracle 11g.